# Remove text between [ ]

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have

```
string = 'blah blah [unwanted text] blah'
```

How do I use PHP to return `'blah blah blah'`? I.e. I want to remove the text between square brackets. Would I use `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

complete solution:

```
$input = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]\W*/i', '', $input);
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but `[^\]]` should be `[^]]` (doesn't require a backslash), and the ignore-case modifier is unnecessary since the pattern contains no letters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:
`\[.*?\]`

`echo preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', "blah blah [unwanted text] blah");`

http://codepad.org/cNvpQOSg

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `preg_replace('/\[[^]]*\]\s*/', '', $your_string)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'blah blah [unwanted text] blah';
$x=explode("[",$string);
$y=explode("]",$string);
echo $x[0].$y[1];
?>
```

-- use this so that you can get the output as you expected.

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one bracketed section in the string.

Comment: Yup, also what if "blah [ blah [ blah [ blah"?